# How to deal with two main function in two separate packages in Java eclipse

Tags: java

I use eclipse. I have two separate packages in the same project. In each package, there is a class that has a main function. But, when I run the class in package2, I find that the main function of the class in package1 is executed instead. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: press on the run or debug buttons in the eclipse editor.

Comment: Okay, then any of the 3 answers will work. If you're ever using a jar then you can specify the main class in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in eclipse right click on class and select "Run/As java application". It will run correct `main()`.

Comment: When I right click the class, it show me `Run Configuration` option only.

Comment: @Jury A It should show Run As > Java Application (also in the toolbar icon, BTW) when it detects a proper main() method. Double-check it is correctly declared.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the run/debug launch configuration dialog and set the <kbd>Main class</kbd> field on the <kbd>Main</kbd> tab to the class that contains the desired main method.

Answer (score 0):

`right click the project -> run as-> run configuration.`

there you will find an option to specify main class. select the main class you want to invoke and press run.

Comment: I don't find the class name I want to invoke its main method listed. I tried to add its name manually, then run. I got the following error: `Error: Main method not found in class myclass , please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: @JuryA did u compile both the packages? build both n then try again